# Juju quickstart failed immediately with: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: juju

I can't seem to get juju quickstart to work using the official documentation

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/juju/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main jujubundlelib all 0.1.8-1 [23.2 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/juju/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main juju-quickstart all 2.1.1+bzr133+ppa36~ubuntu14.04.1 [122 kB]
Fetched 146 kB in 1s (96.8 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package jujubundlelib.
(Reading database ... 227193 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../jujubundlelib_0.1.8-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking jujubundlelib (0.1.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package juju-quickstart.
Preparing to unpack .../juju-quickstart_2.1.1+bzr133+ppa36~ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking juju-quickstart (2.1.1+bzr133+ppa36~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Setting up jujubundlelib (0.1.8-1) ...
Setting up juju-quickstart (2.1.1+bzr133+ppa36~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
vubuntu:~> sudo service mysql stop
mysql stop/waiting
vubuntu:~> juju quickstart
juju quickstart v2.1.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/juju-quickstart", line 34, in <module>
    manage.run(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickstart/manage.py", line 497, in run
    app.ensure_ssh_keys()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickstart/app.py", line 146, in ensure_ssh_keys
    ssh.start_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickstart/ssh.py", line 98, in start_agent
    re.search('SSH_AUTH_SOCK=([^;]+);', output).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
ERROR subprocess encountered error code 1
```

Comment: thanks for your report! We'll look at the issue as soon as possible.
It's surprising that we never encountered this problem:
what's your output from "/usr/bin/ssh-agent"?
Thank you!

Comment: See my updated answer above

Comment: A correct fix would be to just allow a space or an equals sign in between `[= ]` in regex i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this problem is included in the new Quickstart release (2.2.0).
See https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/06/19/juju-quickstart-2-2-0/

Answer (score 3):

They have a bug in their code. I changed the line:

```
re.search('SSH_AUTH_SOCK=([^;]+);', output).group(1))
```

to

```
re.search('SSH_AUTH_SOCK ([^;]+);', output).group(1))
```

It's likely due to the fact that my `/bin/sh` is set to be `tcsh` and not `bash` (which is technically valid in linux, see `chsh`) 
Bash and tcsh set environment variables differently. I haven't verified this, but i theorize it is the reason why it is different.

my output of `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`

```
setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh-WNjKuNpz4WlF/agent.27649;
setenv SSH_AGENT_PID 27650;
echo Agent pid 27650;
```

Comment: This seems to be the culprit. If a bug hasn't already been filed for this let me know.

Comment: I didn't file a bug, i stopped using Juju because then once I got it working, I couldn't figure out how to get it working with my server in my living room. It claimed I had a public IP that was inaccessible, not even sure where the public IP came from since my network card / ISP wouldn't allow another public IP. It's like Juju assumed I was in some sort of cloud environment. Maybe thats where MAAS comes in, I have no idea. But i stopped toying with Juju and set up owncloud by hand at that point =/

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you want to give Juju a try again let me know we'll be happy to work with you to resolve some of these pain points. Juju very much prefers being run on at-scale hardware and there are some touchy areas when it pairs down to just a single machine - yet it's still doable.